# graphql multiple associations

Tags: relational-database, sequelize.js, graphql, graphql-js

I have the following models in sequelize

User

```
User.associate = models => {
    User.hasMany(models.Schedule, {
        onDelete: 'CASCADE',
        foreignKey: 'patient_id',
        sourceKey: 'id',
        as: 'patient'
    });

    User.hasMany(models.Schedule, {
        onDelete: 'CASCADE',
        foreignKey: 'professional_id',
        sourceKey: 'id',
        as: 'professional'
    });
};
```

Schedule

```
Schedule.associate = models => {
    Schedule.belongsTo(models.User, {
        foreignKey: 'patient_id',
        targetKey: 'id',
        as: 'patient'
    });
};

Schedule.associate = models => {
    Schedule.belongsTo(models.User, {
        foreignKey: 'professional_id',
        targetKey: 'id',
        as: 'professional'
    });
};
```

And the following schemas in graphql

user

```
type User {
  id: ID!
  schedules1: [Schedule] @relation(name: "patient")
  schedules2: [Schedule] @relation(name: "professional") 
}
```

schedule

```
type Schedule {
  id: ID!
  date : Date
  patient: User! @relation(name: "patient")
  professional: User! @relation(name: "professional")
```

}

but when try a query of users with schedules like this

```
{
 users{
   id
   name
   schedules1{
     id
   }
  }
}
```

i got the following result

```
{
 "data": {
   "users": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "Gregorio",
      "schedules1": null
   },
  ...
```

My question is, how i can model multiple associations in graphql, i tried the anotation @relation without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

noob mistake... i forgot to add the resolver to the relations.

```
User: {
    patient: async(user, args, { models }) =>
        await models.Schedule.findAll({
            where: {
                patient_id: user.id,
            },
        }),
    professional: async(user, args, { models }) =>
        await models.Schedule.findAll({
            where: {
                professional_id: user.id,
            },
        })
},
```